# Java API for Autosys , cs-7

Tags: scheduling, autosys

I am new to the enterprise scheduler world .
I need to schedule a job in Enterprise schedulers like Autosys, cs-7 using java program.
                                                                                              Is there any java API available for Autosys,cs-7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is Java SDK for the current version of Autosys (CA Workload Automation AE).